# Transform Data using Stored Procedure in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to write a pipeline using Azure Data Factory v2. The data comes from Azure Table Storage, which I then need to transform by retrieving more data from Azure SQL and then need to send to another SQL Database for Insertion.

What I have in mind is to use:

Lookup from Table Storage -> For Each Row -> Execute SP -> Append Data to Lookup Output -> Execute SP to insert in another SQL.

I am not sure if I what I want to achieve is doable with Data Factory or if i'm even approaching this from the right angle.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you mean with the step "Append data to Lookup Output". You cannot add data to the result of a lookup activity.

What you can do is store that output in a table at the first Azure SQL, and perform another Lookup to grab all the data.

Hope this helped!